# Custom WordPress Themes

Tags: wordpress, ibm-cloud

In Bluemix they use something called "WordPress Packagist" to install plugins and themes for WordPress. I was looking trough the Packagist to see if the theme I wanted was in there but no luck.

Is it possible to install custom themes in IBM Bluemix using WordPress? and how if possible?

Comment: can you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Wordpress themes are possible with Wordpress on Bluemix. Checkout these links ([Getting Started](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/wordpress/index.html) and [Using Composer to Manage Your Wordpress Application](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/wordpress/index.html#faq__UsingComposerToManageYourWordPressA)) to install your custom themes. The second link about using Composer specifically focuses on the how to "install your plugins and themes".

If any issues arise or you don't understand these instructions, please comment below.

Thanks!